# Asp.Net MVC throw error when I add the folder 'App_Code'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, app-code

Today, I found a very nice feature giving me the ability to add cshtml helper. To be able to do that, I must put cshtml file in a folder named 'App_Code' and then adding into a code that looks like that:

```
@using System.Security.Policy

@helper jQuery(){
   if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
   {
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   }
   else
   {
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   }
}
```

The problem is immediatly after adding this folder with just one file, when I try to access page in browser, I receive a server error.

*"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/[Port]...*

I already have code into other folders of my project.

Must I have to move all my code into the 'App_Code' folder or is there any trick to keep my existing structure but with this new 'App_Code' folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use helpers within the helper so they are not as helpful as you might have initially thought :-)

Things like `Html` and `Url` don't exist within those helper functions. So if you need to use them, you will have to pass them as parameters:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Security.Policy

@helper jQuery(UrlHelper urlHelper)
{
   if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
   {
        <script src="@urlHelper.Content("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   }
   else
   {
        <script src="@urlHelper.Content("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   }
}
```

and when calling pass the instance of the current UrlHelper to it:

```
@Foo.jQuery(Url)
```

Comment: I search on the web and found a guy saying this: "All MVC project by default are Web Application Projects (WAP) instead of Web Site projects. This means that there's no need for an App_Code folder since WAPs always get compiled anyway. That means that all *.cs files in your project will get compiled, as opposed to Web Site projects where only *.cs files in your App_Code folder would get compiled." If I understand correctly, I can't have both code in a App_Code folder and in other folder in my project.

Comment: You can have `App_Code` with Razor. Don't worry. Just make sure that this folder doesn't contain any `.cs` files. Only Razor stuff: `.cshtml`.

Comment: Ok, I just figure out what you said! The reason why my browser returns an error was because my project don't compile my code. Your a genius guy !!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Just for fun, do you have a job Darin? How can you have 341k while working 8 hours a day? Sorry, .... how can you have 341k in all cases except having 250 IQ and searching on the web 24 hours a day? Thank you again for saving my a lot of time in my life ;)